# How to close a specific handle that is an "Event" Type in Sysinternals?

Tags: cmd, roblox, sysinternals

What I was doing is trying to close an **"Event"** Type via **cmd.exe**, Let's just say **"\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\ROBLOX_singletonEvent"** in **Sysinternals Process Explorer** in **Handles** Menu:
[RobloxPlayeBeta.exe "\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\ROBLOX_singletonEvent"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6qty.png)
you would see the Event Handle in the **RobloxPlayerBeta.exe** Process, But if I used the **Handle.exe** (The Command-Line Version of Handle GUI in Sysinternals) and used:

```
handle.exe -p RobloxPlayerBeta.exe
```

Result:

```
Nthandle v5.0 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2022 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RobloxPlayerBeta.exe pid: 2272 JAMSTUDIOSLAPTO\jpfau
   40: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows
  2BC: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.19041.1110_none_c0da534e38c01f4d
  378: Section       \Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\windows_shell_global_counters
  3B0: File  (RW-)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc
  3EC: File  (RW-)   C:\Users\jpfau\AppData\Local\Roblox\logs\0.550.0.5500640_20221102T023510Z_Player_CB912_last.log
  498: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll
  554: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll
  558: File  (RWD)   C:\Users\jpfau\AppData\Local\Roblox\logs
  564: File  (RWD)   C:\Users\jpfau\AppData\Local\Temp
  568: Section       \Sessions\1\Windows\Theme1270661836
  590: Section       \Windows\Theme1969318615
  608: Section       \Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\RBXMAINWND-4DAAC10B-9C9A-4471-9218-07310329FD0D
  6B8: File  (RWD)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\RobloxPlayerBeta.exe
  6C4: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll
  6D0: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll
  6D8: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll
  820: Section       \BaseNamedObjects\__ComCatalogCache__
  830: Section       \BaseNamedObjects\__ComCatalogCache__
  834: File  (R--)   C:\Windows\Registration\R00000000000d.clb
  878: File  (R-D)   C:\Windows\System32\en-US\MMDevAPI.dll.mui
  8F0: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\PlatformContent\pc\fonts\NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf
  8F8: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\TwemojiMozilla.ttf
  900: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\RobloxEmoji.ttf
  908: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\NotoSansThaiUI-Regular.ttf
  910: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\NotoSansSinhalaUI-Regular.ttf
  918: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\NotoSansMyanmarUI-Regular.ttf
  920: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\NotoSansKhmerUI-Regular.ttf
  928: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\NotoSansGeorgian-Regular.ttf
  930: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\NotoSansDevanagariUI-Regular.ttf
  938: File  (R--)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc\content\fonts\NotoSansBengaliUI-Regular.ttf
  95C: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll
  A84: File  (R--)   C:\Users\jpfau\AppData\Local\Temp\Roblox\sounds\RBXDD9911DF9B634C3BB2FF5F376495436B
  AB8: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
  AD8: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
  B0C: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
  B10: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll
  B18: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll
  B20: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
  B2C: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll
  B38: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll
  B54: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll
  B64: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll
  B6C: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll
  B70: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
  B94: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll
  BA4: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll
  BAC: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll
  BB4: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll
  BC0: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll
  BC4: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
  BDC: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
  BE8: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
  BEC: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll
  BF4: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll
  BF8: File  (RWD)   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RobloxPlayerBeta.exe pid: 960 JAMSTUDIOSLAPTO\jpfau
   40: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows
   84: File  (RW-)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-93fb1ddae5a243cc
```

You Would see that there is no **"\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\ROBLOX_singletonEvent"** even though it is visible in the GUI in Process Explorer, The Reason I use **'handle -p'** Is to know the hex numerical in the Left Side in order to close that handle by:

```
handle -c {Hex of Handle} -p {TargetProcess}
```

But Because The **"Event"** Handle doesn't seem to be listed in **Handle.exe** I can't close it, I can only close it in the GUI (Process Explorer), Is There a way where you can close a handle such as an **"Event"** Handle?

Comment: a bit late but use `-a` to also see Events in the list of handles (even though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) doesn't list Events has being parts of this option, it does say `all types of handles`) .

Comment: Hmm. Sure 'il try that later.